# How do I perform a first edit?

Tags: discussion, usability

I am trying to earn badges to increase my use of UXSE. To earn the editor badge I need to perform a 'first edit.  How do I do this on UXSE?

Answer (score 2):

Hit the edit link right under the tags of any post.

If you want to edit other users' questions and answers (without waiting for your edits to be approved), you need 2000 rep first.  See Help Center > [Privileges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) > [Edit Questions And Answers](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: Actually, it's possible to suggest edits with just 1 rep. According to [this February 2011 blog article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) "Anonymous, unregistered, and 1 reputation users may now submit suggested edits to most content on our sites."

Comment: @GrahamHerrli That's true. But suggested edits are being reviewed by those having the privileges to make actual edits.